# What is the Best way to consume same webservice hosted with different names on the same server?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

We need to consume SAS webservice in C#. SAS team gave me 2 service names one for development (service_dev) and one for production(service) from the same SAS server. While consuming we need to point dev to dev service and prod to prod service C#.

I have created 2 proxy classes for both the services as the names are different.  In the code I am checking if environment is dev, calling dev service and dependent code else prod service and dependent code. The dependent 100 lines code is both in If else condition. This looks ugly and I feel there should be a better way of doing it. Could someone suggest what is the best way to consume same web service hosted with different names?

Answer (score 0):

You should use DI for that. Have the different implementations of your proxy classes in different assemblies and when in production deploy the one that connects to the prod system. This is typically done automatically, during the package step in a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Is this service running the same code? If so (and you are talking about web services) than they should have the same WSDL and you should only have to reconfigure the URL of one service proxy. (same class)

The URL could then be configured via a config file

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Both services are running same code. When the servcie names are different, just chaing the service URL in the configuration is not working. When I added the proxyclasses, dev one is generated with servicereference.service_dev and prod one is generated with servicereference2.service. If I need to call the methods in side the service I need to use, servicereference1.service_dev in development and servicereference2.service for production. I wanted to generate a common code to call these 2 services.